# In the Stargate series is there any indication whether the 7th symbol of an 8 symbol address is always the same?

Tags: stargate

I get that the first 6 are supposed to be coordinates for the destination and the last (8th in this case) would be the point of origin while the 7th is supposed to be a distance calibration.. but is that always the same symbol, akin to the "1" preceeding long distance phone numbers (or dialing 9 for an outside number) or is it actually different symbols for different distances more like different area codes?

I guess I'm hoping someone within the show has spoken about this or that someone has seen the 7th symbol of both the Asgard home world and Atlantis addresses for comparison.

Comment: Technically it is supposed to be, but the series/editors have failed to see it as a reality every single time the gate is dialed. It is the same as closing the iris before the connection has been made... technically the iris would have been disintegrated if it was in place due to the 'kawoosh.'

Comment: @Odin1806 They've got special rules covering the Iris situation, IIRC if something is close enough to the event horizon is prevents the kawoosh from forming.  This became a plot point in the episode "A Hundred Days" - first they had to bombard the other side with particle beam to destroy the 'iris' covering of molten rock and allow the kawoosh to form.

Comment: You are right. I totally forgot about that episode! Thank you!

Comment: @Odin1806 _"Technically it is supposed to be"_ According to whom? Especially since, as you say, it was never shown that way.

Comment: The area codes analogy is helpful but it's just that - an analogy. Stargates are not phones. In truth we don't know exactly how the co-ordinate system works. Not much point debating it, as a result!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, true enough but in the absence of explicitly stated "facts" there could still be self consistency. Today even our phones aren't phones as they all use some kind of voice over ip protocol while all our "phone analogies" are still based on peg boards you move wires around on :) I agree it doesn't shed much light as it raises more questions but it does suggest the 7th symbol of an 8 symbol address is more like area codes than dialing 9 to get a line outside our Galaxy. The real question is if it's something the writers and producers thought out or just happenstance.

Comment: @JohnA Voice over mobile telephony does not use VoIP. If you're using Skype or Facebook Messenger then that's different. :)

Comment: I think Daniel Jackson answers the question in both the movie and show multiple times. the gates work by a system of cross sectioning a planet location in a 'box' and having a point of origin. Those points don't change, stellar drift just pulls them apart. And sure, in the end we are applying real world logic to a tv show, but, as John mentions, there should still be some consistency to the way things work. Obviously the gates should not work randomly, but still taking you exactly where you want to go. The laws of science should apply as much as possible...Otherwise its not science fiction...

Comment: @Odin 1806, I think they retconned it for "the fifth race". The cynic in me says they added the distance glyph in the 7th spot simply so the guys in the control room could react to the weird non-point-of-origin and build more suspense. Anyway, presumably there'd have to be an atypical control input to tell the gate not to connect on the 7th glyph unless it *specifically doesn't match* your origin point. So I guess that makes some sense.

Comment: @JohnA - No, they still followed the original design. For the 8th symbol addresses however they continued to relate it to making a phone call and you dialed a sort of area or country code before putting in the number. I can't remember off the top of my head which 'code' they referred to but as they showed in the ?pilot? episode for Atlantis the six locator symbols are first, then the area code symbol, and then the point of origin to complete the 'long distance address.' I like to think for that first 8 symbol dial the device Jack built was able to override any program code for Earth's gate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Apparently both destinations have different sequences. Completely:

[image: Multiple screenshots showing the 7th symbol is different in different cases]

On the left (the old CRT monitor) is Asgard, on the right is Atlantis.

Comment: So do you think that would be 38 seperate distance ranges or 38 seperate volumes of space/galaxy clusters? Even 2 to the 38th would be almost 30 trillion times farther than a 7 symbol address if it's strictly distance... and we know 7 is good out to 90,000 ly, not sure we need that much range if the universe is thought to be less than 100 trillion ly wide, lol. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: @JohnA I think it's enough. My opinion is this vector-style method is good  enough-you get a way to dial 38 distinct galaxies. The way I see it is that you get to dial a gate in other galaxy that's right on it's edge and the you're in different network. Treat them like a changing station, and then you can go to the next galaxy, then the next... it's enough. Remember gate network operates on "local" coordinate system, so you have to change eventually. It is sound logic.

Comment: Nice. I recently read the MWG is thought to have up to *24* satellite galaxies within 1M ly but many of them are very tiny globular clusters less than 2000 ly wide and a couple larger (but still pretty small) ones that are either within the 90K ly limit (?) of 6 symbol addressing of the MW or of the Earth itself. In SGU we see Destiny's path (and so also its seedships) intersected both Pegasus *and* Andromeda, interestingly, but those smaller ones may not show up at the scales shown. Food for thought, eh?